# Limit of 2 variable function

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to determine the limit of this function:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,2)} \frac{xy^2-4xy-y^2+4x+4y-4}{x^2+y^2-2x-4y+5}$$
I tried to approach in many different ways, such as
$$\lim_{t\to 1} f(t,2t) \quad, \quad\lim_{t\to 1} f(t,2) \quad, \quad \lim_{t\to 2} f(1,t) $$
But i got that the limit is 0 for all of them, tried with polar coordinates but it seems hopeless to get the limit!
How should I think there? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try simplifications : $ \frac{xy^2-4xy-y^2+4x+4y-4}{x^2+y^2-2x-4y+5}=\frac{?}{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2}$

Comment: Then the answer is $0$. Are you doubt the answer $0$, or are you worried there is another limit when you change the way (x,y) approach (1,2)?

Comment: One more: $\frac{ab^2}{a^2+b^2}\leqslant \frac{ab^2}{2ab}$

Comment: I thought that we cant draw any conclusion if the limit is 0, or am I wrong?

Comment: If the limit is definitely $0$, which conclusion you want more?

Comment: @zkutch what he means is that if the limit is zero along the lines he tested it on, that doesn't prove the limit is zero because the limit might not be zero (for example, along other lines).

Comment: @Adam Rubinson. If he/she thinks so, then it's correct, but it needs firstly prove, that limit is $0$. I gave him $2$, hints, but, yet, without result.

Comment: @zkutch In order to avoid considering cases $a\neq 0$ or $b\neq $ I prefer $${ab^2\over a^2+b^2} =a{b^2\over a^2+b^2}\le a ,\quad a>0$$

Comment: Agree, @Ryszard Szwarc. As you can see José Carlos Santos used same in his answer.

Comment: @zkutch Your inequality could be rewritten $${ab^2\over a^2+b^2}={2ab\over a^2+b^2}{b\over 2}\le {b\over 2}$$ and there is no need to consider cases.

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc. My second comment above gave same, the questioner needed only to reduce the fraction, but he did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x,y)=xy^2-4xy-y^2+4x+4y-4$ and $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2-2x-4y+5$. Then, for each $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$,\begin{align}f(x,y)&=f\bigl((x-1)+1,(y-2)+2\bigr)\\&=(x-1)(y-2)^2\end{align}and\begin{align}g(x,y)&=g\bigl((x-1)+1,(y-2)+2\bigr)\\&=(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2.\end{align}Therefore\begin{align}\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,2)}\frac{xy^2-4xy-y^2+4x+4y-4}{x^2+y^2-2x-4y+5}&=\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,2)}\frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}\\&=\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,2)}\frac{(x-1)(y-2)^2}{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2}\\&=\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,2)}(x-1)\overbrace{\frac{(y-2)^2}{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2}}^{\phantom{[0,1]}\in[0,1]}\\&=0.\end{align}

Comment: This was very helpful! thank you sir!:)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.